# Amazon Lex version 2 - Session Timeout exception

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-lex, aws-sdk-nodejs

Luego de dos semanas de investigacion y prueba aun no logro encontrar una solucion con AWS.LexRuntimeV2. I create a simple Bot in order to connecto with my nodejs app... If I send the messages quickly using LexRuntimeV2, it will not throw any error, **but if it took more than 5 minutes to send a message, after establishing the connection, it throws me an exception:**

> **'The session has been destroyed'**

This is my code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const uniqid = require('uniqid');
const { LexRuntimeV2 } = require('@aws-sdk/client-lex-runtime-v2');

class AmazonLexV2 {
constructor(credentials) {
    this.botName = credentials.bot_name;
    this.alias = credentials.bot_alias;
    this.apiVersion = credentials.apiVersion;
    this.region = credentials.region;
    this.locale = credentials.locale;

    this.lexruntime = new LexRuntimeV2({
        apiVersions: credentials.apiVersion,
        correctClockSkew: false,
        region: credentials.region,
        customBackoff: this.retry(),
        connectTimeout: 120000 * 10,
        timeout: 120000 * 10,
        credentials: new AWS.Credentials({
            accessKeyId: credentials.access_key_id, 
            secretAccessKey: credentials.secret_access_key,
            expired: false
        }),
        logger: 'error'
    })
}

async sendTextMessageToAWS(textMessage, sessionId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.lexruntime.recognizeText({
            botAliasId: this.alias,
            botId: this.botName,
            text: textMessage,
            localeId: this.locale,
            sessionId: (sessionId) ? sessionId : uniqid()
        }, (err, response) => {
            if (err && err.message === "The session has been destroyed") {
                resolve(err.message);
            } else if (err) reject(err);        
            else {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response, undefined, 2));
                resolve(response);
            }
        })
    })
}
```

I dont know how to avoid that session destruction! Could anybody help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The default Lex session lifetime is 5 minutes. You can change that though.
Please have a look at this guide in the documentation.
[Setting Session Timeout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/context-mgmt-session-timeout.html)